# Type mismatch. Required: FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatObject, ChatVoiceViewHolders>? Found:

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am porting an Java Code to Kotlin and It's throwing an Type Miss matched error.

Java Code :

```
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatObject, ChatVoiceViewHolders> firebaseRecyclerAdapterChats;
    firebaseRecyclerAdapterChats = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatObject, ChatVoiceViewHolders>(
            ChatObject.class,
            R.layout.item_messages_video_call,
            ChatVoiceViewHolders.class,
            dbMessagingMy
    ) {}
```

Kotlin Code :

```
private var firebaseRecyclerAdapterChats: FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatObject, ChatVoiceViewHolders>? = null
    firebaseRecyclerAdapterChats = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatObject?, ChatVoiceViewHolders?>(
            ChatObject::class.java,
            R.layout.item_messages_video_call,
            ChatVoiceViewHolders::class.java,
            dbMessagingMy
    ) {}
```

but my Koltin code is throwing an error :

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatObject, ChatVoiceViewHolders>?
Found:
```

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

(Class<ChatObject?>!, Int, Class<ChatVoiceViewHolders?>!, FirebaseArray!)   
where T = ChatObject?, VH = ChatVoiceViewHolders? for
constructor FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<T : Any!, VH : RecyclerView.ViewHolder!>(modelClass: Class<T!>!, modelLayout: Int, viewHolderClass: Class<VH!>!, snapshots: FirebaseArray!)
defined in com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

(Class<ChatObject?>!, Int, Class<ChatVoiceViewHolders?>!, Query!)   
where T = ChatObject?, VH = ChatVoiceViewHolders? for    
constructor FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<T : Any!, VH : RecyclerView.ViewHolder!>(modelClass: Class<T!>!, modelLayout: Int, viewHolderClass: Class<VH!>!, ref: Query!) defined in com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

One more point, In my Java code I am working with AppcompatActivity and In my Kotlin Code I am working with BaseActivity..

Is there anything I am doing wrong?
how can I solve this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared your variable as `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatObject, ChatVoiceViewHolders>` but then you try to set value to it which is `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatObject?, ChatVoiceViewHolders?>`.

So change

```
object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatObject?, ChatVoiceViewHolders?> {
```

to this

```
object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatObject, ChatVoiceViewHolders> {
```

The reason why this gives you an error is because Kotlin is more strict about nullability rules. Java does not care so much about it. You were saying that I declare a variable which can have only non-null values but then after that you try to assign a value to it which can have null values.